# React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using typescript with React. Whenever I pass props to function or destructure the props to {text} e.g. I get an error that says "Binding element 'text' implicitly has an 'any' type". Although I can bypass this with using `const Example = ({text}:any) => { return () }` or `const Example = ({text}:{text:string}) => { return () }`
it is not efficient for me. I wanted to ask if you can teach me any good way to overcome this without props argument itself but the destructured version of it.

Note: I see that I couldn't explain my problem well. I'm using Typescript because I want to use its type checking functionality. Giving every prop "any" type is ok but when I try to give every prop its own type e.g `const Example = ({Text, Number, RandomCrap,}: {Text: string; Number: number; RandomCrap: any;}) => {return ();}` It looks like this. Is this the only way?

Answer: Instead of  cramming my code like above I can define types elsewhere like
`type PropsType = {Text: string; Number: number; RandomCrap: any;};`
and use it in my function like `const Header = ({ Text, Number, RandomCrap }: PropsType) => {return ()}`
Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Why do you say it's inefficient? If you think it's too much code, you can disable `no-implicit-any`. Or remove TS altogether, as you're basically not using it if you just want `any` everywhere. If you want to have compile time safety, you need to let TS know what the types are, so it verifies you use them correctly. E.g, you're not actually passing `{TEXT: "hello"}` instead when you expect `{text: "hello"}`.

Comment: For functional components: ```const Example: React.FC<{ text: string }> = ({ text }) => <></>;```

Comment: Why not use `{text}: Props` where `Props` is your props type. Then TypeScript will now of what type `text` is. Maybe I'm missing something due to my limited knowledge of React...

Comment: I edited the question, as you can see if I use a special type I need to pass it like {text}:{text:string} this. As there are more props It gets very cramped. Isn't there are the way to define their types anywhere else and pass them in function?

Comment: Please share your code and point out which line has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a type for your whole `props` object:

```
type PropsType = {
    text: string
} 
const Example = ({text}: PropsType) => { return () }

// or
const Example1: React.FunctionComponent<PropsType> = ({text}) => { return () }
```

Comment: Thank You So Much!! I just started feeling stupid but you gave the answer I was looking for.